# What is the average length of threads criss-crossing a hollow sphere?

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

Imagine a hollow sphere of radius $R$ that has a large, random (but even) number of holes in it. The surface density of the holes is constant. Threads criss-cross the sphere at random, from one hole to another. What is the average length of these threads?

It is a multiple of $R$ - but which one?

P.S. This is not homework. It is a bet among friends. I say $\frac{4R}{3}$, my pal says that it is larger.

Comment: It would be great if you could [edit] the question to add the information on how you reached your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the article on [Sphere Line Picking](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphereLinePicking.html) at MathWorld.

Fix one point $p$; then the density of uniformly picked points on the surface of the unit sphere at angle $\theta$ from $p$ is $\frac12\sin\theta$, and the distance from $p$ to a point at angle $\theta$ is $\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+(1-\cos\theta)^2}=\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}$, so the average distance is

$$
\int_0^\pi\sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}\frac12\sin\theta\mathrm d\theta=\frac12\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{2-2u}\mathrm du=\frac12\left[-\frac13(2-2u)^{\frac32}\right]_{-1}^1=\frac43\;.
$$

Since the distance scales with the radius of the sphere, for a sphere with radius $R$ the average distance is $\frac{4R}3$, so it seems that you win the bet.